# Parse Server Initialize error in React Js

Tags: reactjs, parse-server

I've been trying to initialize parse into my react js project, but the screen turns blank and the error message in the console is "Super expression must either be null or a function", I'm trying to authenticate a user with a username and password.

ApiConfig File

```
import Parse from "parse";

const APP_ID = "FortCore";
const SERVER_URL = "https://test.fortcoretech.com/api";

Parse.initialize(APP_ID);
Parse.serverURL = SERVER_URL;

export default Parse;
```

login file

```
import { Card, LoginForm, LoginStyle, Navbar } from "./styled";
import Logo from "../../assets/logo.svg";
import FLogo from "../../assets/flogo.svg";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "../../globalStyle/GlobalStyle";
import { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import Parse from "../../api/ApiConfig";

function LoginScreen() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const user = await Parse.User.logIn(username, password);
      const isAdmin = user.get("adminStatus") === "super";

      console.log(user);

        if (isAdmin) {
          console.log("User is an admin");
        } else {
          console.log("You do not have admin privileges");
        }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Invalid username or password");
    }

    toast.success("Successfully Logged in");
    localStorage.setItem("isAdmin", "isAdmin");
    navigate("/");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar>
        <div className="content">
          <img src={FLogo} alt="" />
          <p>Admin Portal</p>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
      <LoginStyle>
        <Card>
          <img src={Logo} alt="" />
          <p className="subtext">Admin Authentication</p>

          {/* form  */}

          <LoginForm onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter username"
              disabled={loading}
              required
            />

            <label>Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              disabled={loading}
              placeholder="Enter password"
              required
            />

            <div className="div">
              <div className="forgot">
                <Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot your password?</Link>
              </div>

              <Button type="submit">
                {!loading ? "Login" : <div className="loader"></div>}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </LoginForm>
        </Card>
      </LoginStyle>
    </>
  );
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: I think `super` expression should be inside the function like this: `const isAdmin = user.get("adminStatus" === "super");`

Answer (score 0):

`super` expression should be inside the function to check `adminStatus` like this:

```
const isAdmin = user.get("adminStatus" === "super");
```

I hope this solves your issue!

Comment: Thank you, I tried it still doesn't work, then I try commenting out the function, but left the parse import, and still gives the same error, I'm thinking it has something to do with the parse package. My project was created using npm vite@latest, could that be a problem with parse as well?

Comment: Yes, maybe that problem can create by vite@latest. Could you please post error output to your ques? Or maybe any codesandbox example? Or the thing you could do like only getting `adminStatus` as `super` like this: `user.get("super")`